# Detect keyboard input javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am writing a script where I need to know if a user has pressed <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+p</kbd>. How do I do this. Help would be appreciated. the problem is as soon as the user presses <kbd>ctrl+s</kbd> the page doesn't go to script, it directly gets saved.

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery

Comment: I suggest to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860759/cant-override-ctrls-in-firefox-using-jquery-hotkeys) (btw, maybe your question is a duplicate).

Answer (score 4):

Updated:[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4wSUS/)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if (e.keyCode==80 && e.ctrlKey)
    $("body").append("<p>ctrl+p detected!</p>");
});
```

Comment: nah..this is not working..it's showing an error in e.ctrl

Comment: Updated code check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a script that listens to and cancels the onkeydown event so the browser doesn't do the default behavior. Or maybe use a script like this? http://www.stepanreznikov.com/js-shortcuts/

Comment: well guys , it worked and here is the code.                     <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src='jquery.min.js'>
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='shortcuts.js'>
 </script> 

<script>
alert('hi');

shortcut.add("Ctrl+S",function() {
 alert("Hi there!");
});


</script>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
 include www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/shortcut.js and save it in the same folder as you html code