# Why does prompt() defeat e.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/sueM7/4/ - brings up the "Save As" dialog when you enter Ctrl+S in the result window, even though the code contains  e.preventDefault(); The problem is the prompt() on line 5 of the JavaScript.  If you comment out line 5 the e.preventDefault() properly blocks the "Save As" dialog.

Does anyone know what's happening here, and how I can run the prompt line AND block the "Save As"?

Thanks.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("got Ctrl+S");
 var groupName = prompt("Group Name: ", "abc");
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Many of the built-in keyboard shortcuts can't be interrupted, thankfully. This is by design, you likely cannot circumvent it, nor should you be able to. It's annoying enough when sites are able to interfere with right-clicking as a means of copy-protection, the last thing I want is for them to start blocking shortcuts like View  Source.

Comment: works as expected for me on my mac. @meagar when you compose en email you can use ctrl+s to save as a draft.

Comment: Hm, in the fiddle when I have focus on the result pane and do Ctrl+S, it works exactly as you want it to - no Save As box. If the focus is elsewhere, or on the browser itself, Ctrl+S is not captured by the fiddle. So it works sort-of in Chrome?

Comment: Working in Chrome, not in FF for me.

Comment: @Jonathan That's because on the mac the save shortcut is Command+S, so Ctrl works just fine :)

Comment: works for me too.  Linux + Chrome or Firefox.  CTRL+S = save like on windows but this code works properly. @BrianDHall losing focus in a fiddle takes away the event handlers from that fiddle too (unless they are directly affecting it like resize).

Comment: Indeed, in fiddle, this is an iFrame, so, out of the iFrame, event listener will not act. In firefox, the code is doing the job, but the saveAs window is opening too. It depend on the browser.

Comment: No one is address the prompt line, which is what breaks it for me, in FF. What is the prompt() doing that lets the event get through to its default action?

Comment: This is difficult as at least personally I am unable to reproduce the behavior. prompt() shouldn't matter, but I suppose there could be some issue with event bubbling. event.stopPropagation() probably won't do anything for you as this is a window event listener, but I suppose it wouldn't hurt to give it a try. EDIT: Actually, I think have an answer using this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't override ctrl+s in Firefox using jQuery Hotkeys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860759/cant-override-ctrls-in-firefox-using-jquery-hotkeys)

Comment: If the prompt is what causes this, you could replace it with one made by you, or by a library like jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that apparently Firefox has some very tricky non-synchronicity regarding it's alerts(), and I think prompt() may be causing this same problem for you. See [Can't Override Ctrl+S in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860759/cant-override-ctrls-in-firefox-using-jquery-hotkeys).

Suggested answer from there is:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+s', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert('saving?');
  return false;
});
```

The key seems to be managing to get the prevention called before Firefox runs out of sequence and fires a default action while its popping out alert/prompt windows. If this doesn't work, I'd try a short timer - which is a filthy hack, admittedly - to give Firefox 100-150 milliseconds to get it's act together before calling out a prompt(). This is too short to cause obvious interface delays in this use case, and it should band-aid fix the Firefox bug/feature regarding user alerts.

Comment: i expect even a 0 delay (or `setImmediate`) would work, since any callback fired from a timer happens _after_ the current event queue finishes.  which makes it less of a hack, right?  right?  :)

Comment: @Eevee I'm inclined to not only believe you, but would try to implement it as such and refuse to test it as a matter of principle. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setImmediate Hm, reminds me of one of my favorite unattributed quotes: "I'm sure it'll be fine."