# Crossbrowser CTRL+S JavaScript problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, jquery-events

I see this is very popular question, but i still cannot find right solution.

I'm trying to call function (save) on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> pressed inside my textarea. I found that Chrome or IE needs "keydown" and FireFox needs "keypress".

Actually, Firefox registers "keydown" - calls my "alert" but don't prevent browser "Save As" dialog.

I tried to put both events, - then FireFox prevents Save As dialog, but calls my Alert twice.

Here's code:

```
$("#mytextarea").on("keypress keydown",function(e) { 
    if ((e.which == '115' || e.which == '83' ) && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("Ctrl-s pressed");
         return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

[JS fiddle - try to open with FF](https://jsfiddle.net/r1y2d3dy/1/)

Does anyone have real crossbrowser solution?

Answer (score 0):

For a save browser compatibility you can also use one of the the following javascript libraries:

- [mice](https://craig.is/killing/mice)
- [openjs](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/#)
- [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster)

with jquery for example:

- [jquery.hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

Comment: Still no "safe" xbrowser solution... check what happens with mice: https://jsfiddle.net/jy4kfxeL/ - Firefox will fire alert and open dialog window

Answer (score 0):

I found hint that looks like working solution at:
[Can't override ctrl+s in Firefox using jQuery Hotkeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860759/cant-override-ctrls-in-firefox-using-jquery-hotkeys)

it looks like i should wrap function in setTimeout...
it works for now.